# Can't install .NET Framework 3.5 feature (0x800f0922)

Tags: .net, windows

I have a Windows 10 machine that needs to run some programs that require .NET 3.5. Every time I try to install it I get an error: Can't install .NET Framework 3.5 feature (0x800f0922)

I've tried literally everything I've found on the web on how to fix this and nothing is working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you run it as administrator and you are an administrator on the machine? Something to try: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-net-framework-3-5-installation-error-0x800f0922/

Comment: Are you installing this from 'Control Panel', 'Programs and Features', 'Turn Windows features on and off'? Or trying to install a binary you've downloaded?

Comment: Related question on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/946988/cant-install-net-3-5-on-windows-10

Comment: I've run it as administrator.

Comment: I've installed it from Program & Features, as well as used the web installer, and the full offline installer, and also tried installing it off the Windows disc.

Answer (score 0):

Either start up Control Panel and go to Programs->Programs and Features, or display Windows Settings and go to Apps and click on Programs and Features under Related Settings.

In Programs and Features go to "Turn Windows features on or off". In the dialog that displays, ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" should be listed. Check that and click OK. I don't recall if you will need to reboot at that point.

Comment: That gives the same error as if I run the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I've run into NET 3.5 install issues this has fixed it for me:

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Update the path to the SXS source (CD,USB,etc) as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks I tried that numerous times and it gives the same error

Comment: Logs say:

[8924] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1381): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[8924] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(641)
[8924] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2897)
[8924] [0x8007007b] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1381): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[8924] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(641)
[8924] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2897)

Comment: Another thing to try is through Powershell (run as admin): 

    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "NetFx3" -All